How to open datepicker when tapping on an icon?
I have an icon on the UI and when tapping on it I need to open the calendar directly.
<DatePicker 
    x:Name="DA_DatePicker"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    IsVisible="False"
    Date="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
    MinimumDate="2024-01-01"
    MaximumDate="2025-12-31"
    Format="MM/dd"
    DateSelected="OnDateSelected"/>

Is there any way to do it on MAUI? When tap on it I set the visibility to true, but on UI only current date is showing.

For android, you can use handler.PlatformView.PerformClick(); to make the DatePicker appear when image was tabbed. For iOS DA_DatePicker.Focus(); will open the datepicker.
    public void CalendarClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            DA_DatePicker.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            var handler = DA_DatePicker.Handler as IDatePickerHandler;
#if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.PerformClick();
#endif
        }
    }


This is a known issue in MAUI : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8946
And there is also an open SO answer for this Focusing on DatePicker does not work MAUI

On the suggested answer, they are loading the calendar from datepicker not from an icon.

I need to load the datepicker when tapping an icon

The same logic applies, the focus event is not available
